# pass arguments to python program in shell

Tags: shell, python

I am unable to run python script within a shell script. Following is the script.sh file where 3 arguments are being passed to the python script.

```
python main.py 1.0 0.1 10
```

The python program is not reading the arguments. When same line is run in command line terminal, it runs fine.

<<>>
I just checked that by defining the arguments in `main.py` hardcoded and running the command without arguments. It still doesn't work. The `main.py` is using some other files also which are located in the same directory. Also, the script is also located in the same directory.

Comment: main.py is a complicated program but it runs totally fine when executed directly with the terminal and with the same arguments.

Comment: What errors are you getting when put inside the shell script? Is the shell script and the python script are on the same directory?

Comment: Yes, the shell script and the python script are in same directory. The error looks like this:
`    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
        from cell import Cell
      File "/home/hasnain/Data/Studies/Courses/Current_Courses/Seminar/Code/Experiments/Without_LTS1/cell.py", line 9
    def __init__(self, width:float, h:float=0.0, hu:float=0.0, hv:float=0.0,  flux_r=array((0.0, 0.0, 0.0)),  flux_l=array((0.0, 0.0, 0.0)), dt_cfl=0.0, kmax=0.0, k = 0.0):
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Can you post the content of `script.sh` in full?

Comment: I have tried it both ways, with nested loops and with hardwired argumenrs
In nested loops, it is like:
`
arr_t=("1.0")
arr_dt=("0.00158")
arr_np=("10")
for t in "${arr_t[@]}"
do
for dt in "${arr_dt[@]}"
do
for np in "${arr_np[@]}"
do
    python main2.py $t $dt $np
echo $t
echo $dt
echo $np
done
done
done`

Without loops it was:

`python main.py 1.0 0.1 10  `

It does not work either way.

Comment: The first two arguments are `float` and the third argument is `int`.

Comment: @heemayl I just checked, `main.py` by removing the arguments and defining them in `main.py` (hardcoded). It doesn't run without arguments either. `

main.py` has some other dependency python files which are also in the same directory.

Answer (score 2):

From the `SyntaxError` you have pasted, it sounds like you are running the script under the wrong version of python, specifically Python 2 instead of Python 3 (because the `SyntaxError` may be complaining about the annotations, [which only exist in Python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/)).

If you read the error you actually got, you can see that this really doesn't have anything to do with passing arguments (the title of your question) at all.

The correct solution is to not invoke the script by prefixing it with the interpreter name, but to let it invoke its own interpreter:

```
./main.py 1.0 0.1 10
```

instead of

```
python main.py 1.0 0.1 10
```

If it's properly written, the script will have a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) at the start that specifies what interpreter it needs to run under, and that will be `python3` or something similar.

By letting the script specify its own interpreter, the calling script need not know or care which interpreter is required. The script can even be rewritten to use a different language altogether (or it can be replaced with a compiled binary that isn't a script at all) and the callers don't have to be modified to call it differently.